# Table not updating every time record is added

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a restaurant reservation system in the works and I'm having troubles with adding the reservation to my table. I have a button that adds the reservation through a VBA on-click event.

This is the code I used and when I try to add a reservation, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't:

```
Private Sub AddRes_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO tblReserve(CustomerID, ResDate, ResTime, TableNum) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.txtCustID & ",'" & Me.txtResDate & "','" & _
Me.txtResTime & "','" & Me.txtTableNum & "')"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an error message when it doesn't work?

Comment: nope, no error. all the tables are closed, just the form. when i check the table after making a reservation, it doesn't show up. i originally had a subform but that too wasn't updating when i add a reservation, even with a requerying.

Comment: Try including the `dbFailOnError` option: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO ...", dbFailOnError`  Does that give you any information when the `INSERT` fails?

Comment: You're welcome.  Please submit an answer to describe how you resolved this question.  And you can accept your answer when the system allows.   Thanks.